# Display results horizontally

Tags: sql-server, for-xml

Using SQL Server 2005

I want to have `itemid, deliverydate, remainpurchphysical` display horizontally.

Currently I am using the `FOR XML PATH` and this works.

When the results are multiple delivery dates per itemid I want to have them display a bit better

```
  [ITEMID]  [DELIVERYDATE AND REMAINPURCH]
  -----------------------------------------
  [1234]    [14/14/2014 25 | 15/15/2015 27 | 16/16/2016 28]
```

preferable with a | between each date

Here is the current code

```
-select itemid, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, deliverydate, 103),remainpurchphysical
--from purchline where purchstatus =1 --and itemid = '00727-s'
SELECT 
    itemid 
    ,deliverydates = STUFF(
                       (SELECT '   ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, deliverydate, 103)
                        FROM purchline b 
                        WHERE b.itemid = a.itemid AND purchstatus = 1 
                        ORDER BY deliverydate 
                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    ,remainpurchphysical = STUFF(
                              (SELECT '   ' + CAST(CONVERT(Decimal(9,0), remainpurchphysical) AS VARCHAR)
                               FROM purchline b 
                               WHERE b.itemid = a.itemid AND purchstatus = 1  
                               ORDER BY deliverydate
                               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM purchline a
WHERE purchstatus =1
GROUP BY itemid
ORDER BY itemid
```

Comment: here is the current code

Comment: _where_ is the current code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

something like this,

```
SELECT
     [ITEMID],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ' | ' + [date]
          FROM Table1
          WHERE [ITEMID] = a.[ITEMID]
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS DateList
FROM Table1 AS a
GROUP BY [ITEMID]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40710/4)

Comment: Hello JW My Quantity is not in the same field i have 3 fields. ItemID, DeliveryDate and RemainPurchPhysical